# Changing the color of the offset in scientific notation in matplotlib

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I am plotting some curves using twin-axis and also scientific notation. I have set some color to the label but the setting don't seem to affect the power indicator of the scientific notation of its axis. Is there any trick?

[Example](http://imageupload.org/?di=1212976802234)

Here is my code:

```
fig = pylab.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# Plotting the data
plot_ax1, = ax1.plot()
plot_ax2, = ax2.plot()

# Setting the label colors
ax2.yaxis.set_offset_position('right') # To set the power indicator of ax2 
ax1.yaxis.label.set_color(plot_ax1.get_color())
ax2.yaxis.label.set_color(plot_ax2.get_color())

# Setting the ticker properties     
tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
ax1.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(0,0), axis='y')
ax2.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(0,0), axis='y')        
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=plot_ax1.get_color(), **tkw)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=plot_ax2.get_color(), **tkw)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

# Setting the legend
lines = [plot_ax1, plot_ax2]
ax1.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines],'upper left')
```

Comment: You could have a look at the matplotlib mailing list. http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=matplotlib-users

Comment: I guess tick_params was added to matplotlib recently: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/whats_new.html#tick-params
It seems like 'colors' should change both tick colors and and tick label colors, but it isn't. Did you try explicitly setting 'labelcolor'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably just an oversight that `tick_params` doesn't already do this, but you can simply set it manually.

For example, just add these two lines to your example code:

```
ax1.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_color(plot_ax1.get_color())
ax2.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_color(plot_ax2.get_color())
```

As a more complete example, using your code snippet above and some random data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

numdata = 100
t = np.linspace(0.05, 0.11, numdata)
x1 = np.cumsum(np.random.random(numdata) - 0.5) * 40000
x2 = np.cumsum(np.random.random(numdata) - 0.5) * 0.002

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# Plotting the data
plot_ax1, = ax1.plot(t, x1, 'r-', label='x1')
plot_ax2, = ax2.plot(t, x2, 'g-', label='x2')

# Setting the label colors
ax2.yaxis.set_offset_position('right') # To set the power indicator of ax2 
ax1.yaxis.label.set_color(plot_ax1.get_color())
ax2.yaxis.label.set_color(plot_ax2.get_color())

# Setting the ticker properties     
tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
ax1.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(0,0), axis='y')
ax2.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(0,0), axis='y')        
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=plot_ax1.get_color(), **tkw)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=plot_ax2.get_color(), **tkw)

ax1.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_color(plot_ax1.get_color())
ax2.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_color(plot_ax2.get_color())

ax1.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

# Setting the legend
lines = [plot_ax1, plot_ax2]
ax1.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines],'upper left')

plt.show()
```

[image]